# str_replace keys in multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I have a multidimensional array like the following:

```
Array (
    [results] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [object_id] => 13
            [id] => 13
            [idno] => e00110-o00005-2010-PROG
            [display_label] => La Bohème / PUCCINI - 2010
            [ca_objects.description] => Libreto de Luigi Illica y Giuseppe Giacosa basado en Escenas de la vida bohemia de Henri Murger Nueva producción – Teatro Colón
            [ca_objects.type_id] => Programa de mano
        )
        //more data here
```

I'm trying to loop the array and replace "object_id" key for "new_id" using str_replace.

```
$str="object_id";//The string to search for

$rep="new_id";//The replacement string


foreach ($array as $value) {
   foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
     foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {
      str_replace($str,$rep,$key3);
       echo $key3." : ".$value3."<br>"; //It gets printed with no changes
     }
    }
  }
```

The above code does not work, can you see what am I doing wrong?.
I tried using strings instead of variables but didn't work either.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `str_replace()` returns the new string, it doesn't modify the string in place.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! Silly me. I'll keep on researching then.

Comment: Do you actually want to modify the keys in the array, or just print the elements with the modified keys?

Comment: @Barmar I want to modify them.

Comment: `str_replace()` is for doing multiple replaces of substrings, but in your example the match is exact for the whole key. Do you need to do substring replacement?

Comment: No, I just want to replace the string "object_id" from the key with a new different string.

Comment: You might also want to look at array_keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...if you really want to use `str_replace()`:

```
$array['results'] = array_map(function($item){
  $keys = implode(',', array_keys($item));
  $keys = str_replace('object_id', 'new_id', $keys);
  return array_combine(explode(',', $keys), array_values($item));

}, $array['results']);
```

The other way - create a new array, then iterate over the old array and assign values from it to the new array, while changing the keys you want:

```
$array['results'] = array_map(function($item){
  $item['new_id'] = $item['object_id'];      
  unset($item['object_id']);
  return $item;

}, $array['results']);
```

(this one will reorder the array, if it matters)

Comment: Thanks! I like the new array aproach!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
  foreach ($value as $key2 => &$value2) {
    $value2[$rep] = $value2[$str];
    unset($value2[$str]);
  }
}
```

It's necessary to iterate over the arrays using references so that the modifications affect the original array, not a copy.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the code. And thanks for the useful information!

Comment: I tried and I ended with an array without the key. Like this Array ( [results] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 13 [idno] => e00110-o00005-2010-PROG [display_label]// etc. I'll try to debug it in order to learn. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

@One Trick Pony: 
I followed your suggestion and created a new array. It was exactly what I needed and I did it by myself!!. Following code creates the new array. Thank you all so much for helping me!

```
 $display=array();
    foreach ($array as $value) {
      foreach ($value as $value2) {
        $display [] = array (
                         'Id del objeto' => $value2['object_id'],
                         'Título' => $value2['display_label'],
                         'Descripción' => $value2['ca_objects.description'],
                         );
              }
    }
```