# replace special character Ã· with ö

Tags: php, html, xml

For a customer I made a XML coupling and that works fine, but in the content there is a character like 'Ã·', that character must be an 'ö'. I've already searched on this and other forums but I couldn't find any solution. Even preg_replace isn't working.

Could somebody help me out?

Content:
Preise sind ohne Mehrwertsteuer. An die abgelesen Laufleistung , abgegeben Massen, Spezifikationen und Gewichten **kÃ·nnen** keine Rechten abgeleitet werden.

Must be converted to:
Preise sind ohne Mehrwertsteuer. An die abgelesen Laufleistung , abgegeben Massen, Spezifikationen und Gewichten **können** keine Rechten abgeleitet werden.

Tried from posts, but not working:

```
$content = $sitemap[0]->description;

// replace line breaks with <br /> 
$html = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($content)); 

$output=str_replace('Ã·', 'ö', $html); 

echo $output;
```

And

```
$content = $sitemap[0]->description;

// replace line breaks with <br /> 
$html = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($content)); 

$output=str_replace('Ã·', 'ö', $html); 

echo $output;
```

Comment: Why should it be replaced? What's the logic behind it? What have you tried so far, in order to achieve this?

Comment: He has his content in many languages like dutch, English and German. The wordt must be können instead of kÃ·nnen - $html = preg_replace('/kÃ·nnen/','konnen', $html);

Comment: I'm next to 100% convinced that your client does indeed enter the correct character, and is being written to file under a different encoding method, and this could very well provide from the way the server's default encoding is set to. @user3366162

Comment: Could you upload the xml file somewhere? I guess it is a combination of wrong encoding and reading the file with the wrong encoding.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit #2:** I'm next to 100% convinced that your client does indeed enter the correct character, and is being written to file under a different encoding method, and this could very well provide from the way the server's default encoding is set to. I was faced with the "**exact**" problem/issue before and couldn't modify the server's settings and had to resort to finding and replacing characters before writing to file.

---

#### Original answer which didn't work, most likely because of my comment above. ^^^

You can achieve this using the [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function.

```
<?php
$replace='kÃ·nnen';
$new=str_replace('Ã·', 'ö', $replace); 

echo $new;
```

will echo `können`

---

### Edit 1

I have tested this and it worked, minus the `[0]->description` since I don't know where the content is pulled from.

```
<?php
$sitemap = "Preise sind ohne Mehrwertsteuer. An die abgelesen Laufleistung , abgegeben Massen, Spezifikationen und Gewichten kÃ·nnen keine Rechten abgeleitet werden.";

// $content = $sitemap[0]->description; // replace line breaks with <br />
$content = $sitemap; // replace line breaks with <br /> 

$html = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($content)); 
$output=str_replace('Ã·', 'ö', $html); 
echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: Isn't working for me, maybe because I need to echo many content?
I have the following content:

Preise sind ohne Mehrwertsteuer. An die abgelesen Laufleistung , abgegeben Massen, Spezifikationen und Gewichten kÃ·nnen keine Rechten abgeleitet werden.

And my currently php is :
$content = $sitemap[0]->description;
    
// replace line breaks with <br />
$html = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($content));

$output=str_replace('Ã·', 'ö', $html); 

echo $output;

But this isn't working it keeps give me kÃ·nnen

Comment: Let me see what else I can come up with. @user3366162

Comment: Is the content "Preise sind ohne Mehrwertsteuer..." inside a variable or inside `$content`? I need to know if that text is coming from that, or is just inside the `<body>` as plain text. @user3366162

Comment: I get the content "Preise sind ohne Mehrwertsteuer..." from an external site map that I put into an variable using $content = $sitemap[0]->description; I get it in plain tekst from the xml that's why I add line breaks. The data in xml is stored as the following : 
<description>
<![CDATA[
Preise sind ohne Mehrwertsteuer. An die abgelesen Laufleistung , abgegeben Massen, Spezifikationen und Gewichten k÷nnen keine Rechten abgeleitet werden.
]]>
</description>

Comment: Ok. I made an edit and tested it, minus the `[0]->description` and it worked for me. @user3366162

Comment: I think it's `[0]->description` that's affecting your output from `$sitemap[0]->description` @user3366162 did you see my edit? Theoretically, this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it works half.
Tried on safari, chrome and firefox but outputs : 
Preise sind ohne Mehrwertsteuer. An die abgelesen Laufleistung , abgegeben Massen, Spezifikationen und Gewichten können keine Rechten abgeleitet werden.
If I directly copy your code and outputs edit it :
Preise sind ohne Mehrwertsteuer. An die abgelesen Laufleistung , abgegeben Massen, Spezifikationen und Gewichten kÃ·nnen keine Rechten abgeleitet werden. if I use it in $content = $sitemap[0]->description;
    
$html = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($content)); 
$output=str_replace('Ã·', 'ö', $html);

Comment: You're welcome. So now it went to `kšnnen` with the `š` that's bizarre. File encoding issue maybe? @user3366162

Comment: Sorry, maked an mistake. If I directly code and paste your code it outputs the right way, but if I use it like : 
$content = $sitemap[0]->description; $html = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($content)); $output=str_replace('Ã·', 'ö', $html);  then not.

Comment: Something tells me you may need to `explode()` it then `implode()` it after, but those are functions I have a hard time with. @user3366162 [**This Q&A**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17202934/) may help.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a try. If I find something I will post it as soon as possible.

Comment: Ok. I'm curious though. Is the `Ã·` characters something the client enters him/herself, or does it appear like that when the `ö` is used? @user3366162

Comment: It's something the client enters, in the original XML file it shows an ÷ instead of Ã / ö. I think that ÷ is the problem at all. After your post with str_replace I've tried also with ÷ instead of Ã but that isn't working to.

Comment: I was faced with something similar before, where I used a function to catch the character(s) before being written to file; that could be an option. @user3366162

Comment: IMHO this is just a workaround until you find other umlauts like öäüÖÄÜ or other non ascii chars. Better try fixing the encoding. I have trouble with it for my answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree 100% @rekire However, OP states that it's the client entering the character.

Comment: After seeing a comment in your answer @rekire I tend to think that the OP's client does enter the `ö` character, but the way the file is being written to, is causing the problem. That could be a "server" related issue which I was faced with myself before and couldn't modify the server's settings and had to resort to finding and replacing characters before writing to file.

Answer (score 0):

When you see a character combination like Ã· on the screen, it is invariably because you have (somewhere in the processing pipeline) content that is encoded in UTF-8, but which is being read by some software component that thinks it is encoded in Latin-1 (or something similar, e.g. Windows CP1252).

The problem is tracing this back through the processing pipeline to find out where the error occurred. It might be at the final stage of displaying the output, or it might be happening earlier. You need to trace the data back through all the processing stages to find out where it is going wrong, and at the point where the "misunderstanding" occurs, change the configuration of one of the miscommunicating components so that the agree on the character encoding they are using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tested and the error seems like that it is in the XML encoding, but when I changed the XML encoding from UTF-8 to Latin-1 / ISO-8859-1 / ISO-8859-15 or Windows-1252 it shows kšnnen instead of können. I've searched on google and WikiPedia and both results say that ISO-8859-1 should be the right one for umlauts. But that isn't working for me..

Comment: Use a hex editor to find out what the actual binary encoding of the offending character is.